# Аутентификация React

Tags: reactjs, redux, auth, react-router

Api после авторизации отсылает jwt token в cookie и уже по нему при следущих запросах предоставляет доступ к данным.

Не могу понять как мне отображать PrivatePage при загрузке приложение если куки уже получен, но пользователь закрыл и снова открыл приложение.

Я пробовал отсылать пустой запрос к апі и если апі давал доступ то в ридакс сторе установить auth: true, а потом использовать условный рендеринг. Не всегда так срабатывало, да и было лишним, мне казалось, отправлять еще один запрос.

Потом хотел после авторизации чтобы в localStorege сохранялось поле auth: true, и уже от него рендерить. Но поле можна легко изменить руками, а соответсвенно приложение потом рендерило приватную стр но без даты.

Не могу понять где выполнять проверку на аутентификацию в клиенте и как соидинить с react-route и redux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Не могу понять как мне отображать PrivatePage при загрузке приложение если куки уже получен, но пользователь закрыл и снова открыл приложение.

При каждом запросе к серверу вместе с запросом должен отсылаться токен в заголовках или в куки. Соответственно сервер, после проверки токена, должен вернуть либо приватные данные, либо сообщение об ошибке. Отдельно устанавливать `auth: true` необязательно. Нужно перед рендером проверить полученные данные. Если сервер вернул (например) `error: 'Access denied'` или код 401, то рендерить сообщение об ошибке вместо данных.